# Counting all results of MySQL query for paging

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a search page, each page featuring 10 results. For that purpose, I would like to display pages numbers at the bottom (like in Google for example) so a user can jump to a specific page result. In order to do that I need to know the overall count of the query (e.g., if I show 10 results per page and the specific query returns 73 rows in my Table, i would need to display links to 8 pages).

The only way I can think of is using the following (obviously inefficient) query:

```
// Query for the current page
$res = mysql_query("select * from TABLE WHERE COL='Sample' LIMIT $offset,10");

// Geeting the total count do I can build links to other pages
$res2 = mysql_query("select COUNT(*) fromTABLE WHERE COL='Sample'");
```

Is that the only way to do it?

Thanks,

Danny

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can [use](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)

```
SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS


mysql> SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tbl_name
    -> WHERE id > 100 LIMIT 10;
mysql> SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

> SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS tells MySQL to
>   calculate how many rows there would be
>   in the result set, disregarding any
>   LIMIT clause. The number of rows can
>   then be retrieved with SELECT
>   FOUND_ROWS()

Comment: Thanks, I guess it is more efficient!

Comment: @Danny: [To SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS or not to SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS?](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/)

Comment: `SQL_COUNT_FOUND_ROWS` is deprecated as of MySQL server v8. [The manual recommends](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) using a separate `COUNT(*)`.